# Office365/Outlook's chat icon feature got disabled

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-teams

update 2021-05-13:

after re-install msteam, the function works now.

---

On my company PC, it has Office 2016 preinstalled, on that, I could easily double click on chat icon in outlook to open a MSTeams chat, but on my laptop, the chat icon got disabled, is the feature has been disabled in Office 365? If not, how could I enable it?

update:

I've search and got that I should enable [Skype for business for the feature to work](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_exchon-mso_o365b/microsoft-teams-chat-icon-is-disabled-on-the/155f9c88-1892-4b64-b29b-37bed7017295), but when I've installed Office 365 from office.com / [Install Office] / Double Click on "OfficeSetup.exe" there is no option for me to config.

[image: can not open Teams Chat from Outlook]
[image: Outlook Version]
[image: the good old chat icon in office 2016]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I could still start a chat in Outlook 365(same version with yours) when I disable the skype meeting / teams meeting add-ins, so I think it may not be related to these add-ins.

But according to my experience, it would be grayed if you haven't opened and logged into your account in teams client, please first check if you have open and logged in to the teams successfully.

Comment: I've manually started and logged in to Teams, then manually started and loggin to Outlook, still disabled too.

Comment: I think there may be any errors on your Outlook or Teams, it's suggested to repair your Outlook and re-install your Teams to check.